# Problems with cut print report <Primefaces>

Tags: primefaces, printing, report

I am new to the forum and starting to develop . I have a problem and do not even know where to look as in Primefaces documentation has nothing about it . created a report page and when the report has more than one page the table is cut in half as shown.

[Image link](http://tinypic.com/r/6h45zo/8)

Answer (score 0):

Both the PF and PF extensions exporter don't support the preventing of pagebreaks inside a table afaik. You have to customize the exporter to achieve this.